# Leetcode C++ error: reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++

when I was doing Leetcode, I wrote my codes as follows:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool compare(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
    {
        return a[1] > b[1];
    };
    
    int maximumUnits(vector<vector<int>>& boxTypes, int truckSize) {
        sort(boxTypes.begin(), boxTypes.end(), compare);
    }
};
```

And then it told me "error: reference to non-static member function must be called", the problem is on "compare" in sort function. But the weird thing is, when I run it on local compiler, it totally works. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: *"when I run it on local compiler, it totally works. "* - No, it doesn't. Not *that* code. No C++ compiler will accept *that* code as-posted as valid precisely because of error reported. Make `compare` static. As a performance bonus, make it's arguments const-references. And `maximumWidth` needs to stop lying. It claims it returns `int`, but make no effort to actually do so.

Comment: Interesting. GCC and Visual Studio both have the same complaint as Leetcode. https://godbolt.org/z/PxdWvG68d Not sure how you avoided it. You should also watch out for the missing return statement GCC issued a warning about

Comment: Maybe someone could tell you why if you said what you are using to compile locally. What is it, GCC 3?

Comment: GCC 3 would barf over the `>>` in `vector<vector<int>>`.

Comment: `bool compare(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)` -- Off-topic, but those vectors should be passed by const reference, not by value: `bool compare(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)`.  Passing by-value makes an entire copy of the vector.  Imagine if `a` or `b` has a million elements in it.  This is why sites like Leetcode and similar "competitive coding" sites do **not** teach C++.  They expect you to know C++ well-enough to not make mistakes (or flaws) like this.  Then let's say your version compiled and sorted -- you now believed you had "good" code, when it was seriously flawed.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I'm a newbie in C++. As for the question, I did compile it successfully on an online open-source C++ compiler. I thought that was the same as my local compiler, and now I know it's not. I have no idea what version of compiler its developer used. During my learning path of C++, I was in a rush and left out a lot of details. Now I found out it's never a good idea to rush in study. I'm gonna go back and brush up on the basics. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Just add static in front of your comparator function

```
class Solution {
public:
    static bool mycomp(const pair<int,int> &a, const pair<int,int> &b)
    {
        if(a.first==b.first)
        {
            return a.second < b.second;
        }
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<pair<int,int>> temp;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            temp.emplace_back(make_pair(nums[i], i));
        }
        
        sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), mycomp);       
        
        return nums;
    }
};
```

Comment: funny how your suggested solution has a different type and implementation than the question

Comment: I just gave a code sample to show the approach.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I now find where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason might be: the **non-static function** `compare()` in the class needs to receive **three** parameters, including the hidden parameter `this`.

In other words, it's real definition is like this: `bool compare(Solution* this, vector<int> a, vector<int> b){}`

However, when you call function `sort()`, it only passes **two** parameters (which are the first two parameters in sort()) into function `compare()`. Thus, there's a mismatch of parameter numbers.

On the other hand, if you define `compare()` as a **static function** in the class, it will no longer need `this` as the hidden parameter. It only accepts **two** parameters, and that's the reason why it works.